# Differentiation of $(x,y)\mapsto g(x+h(x,y))$

Tags: derivatives

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be two differentiable functions.

I would like to compute the differential of $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $T(x,y)=g(x+h(x,y))$.

I get $D T(x,y) = Dg(x+h(x,y))\circ D(x_1(\cdot)+h(\cdot)) = g'(x+h(x,y))\times \big(1+\partial_1 h(x,y) \quad \partial_2 h(x,y)\big)$.

Is it correct?

Comment: If that last bit is a 2-component vector, yep.

Comment: @Randall : It is a matrix with one line and two columns.

Comment: Right.  Same difference.